# PySpark count rows on condition

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, count, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe

```py
test = spark.createDataFrame([('bn', 12452, 221), ('mb', 14521, 330), ('bn', 2, 220), ('mb', 14520, 331)], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
test.show()
# +---+-----+---+
# |  x|    y|  z|
# +---+-----+---+
# | bn|12452|221|
# | mb|14521|330|
# | bn|    2|220|
# | mb|14520|331|
# +---+-----+---+
```

I need to count the rows based on a condition:

```
test.groupBy("x").agg(count(col("y") > 12453), count(col("z") > 230)).show()
```

which  gives

```
+---+------------------+----------------+
|  x|count((y > 12453))|count((z > 230))|
+---+------------------+----------------+
| bn|                 2|               2|
| mb|                 2|               2|
+---+------------------+----------------+
```

It's just the count of the rows, not the count for certain conditions.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`count` doesn't sum *True*s, it only counts the number of non null values. To count the *True* values, you need to convert the conditions to 1 / 0 and then `sum`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cnt_cond = lambda cond: F.sum(F.when(cond, 1).otherwise(0))
test.groupBy('x').agg(
    cnt_cond(F.col('y') > 12453).alias('y_cnt'), 
    cnt_cond(F.col('z') > 230).alias('z_cnt')
).show()
+---+-----+-----+
|  x|y_cnt|z_cnt|
+---+-----+-----+
| bn|    0|    0|
| mb|    2|    2|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: From the show table, is there a way I could extract the values to Python variable? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689509/from-pyspark-agg-function-to-int

Comment: Can I just check my pyspark understanding here: the lambda function here is all in spark, so this never has to create a user defined python function, with the associated slow downs. Correct? This looks very handy.

Comment: @Psidom, could you help me with my conditional count problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470031/how-to-check-if-the-value-at-hand-is-in-a-particular-column-of-some-pyspark-data

Answer (score 37):

Based on @Psidom answer, my answer  is as following

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when,count

test.groupBy("x").agg(
    count(when(col("y") > 12453, True)),
    count(when(col("z") > 230, True))
).show()
```

Comment: Note that the True value here is not necessary - any non null value would achieve the same result, as count() counts non null.

Answer (score 3):

count function skip `null` values so you can try this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def count_with_condition(cond):
    return F.count(F.when(cond, True))
```

and also function in this repo: [kolang](https://github.com/MahdiHGZ/kolang/blob/5e3fc81e64eab8c9e15e16fc8bface7ff2a04e57/kolang/column_functions.py#L323)

Answer (score 3):

Since Spark 3.0.0 there is `count_if(exp)`, see [Spark function documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#count_if)

Comment: I try count_if(exp) in pyspark 3.1.2 but this is not in pyspark.sql.functions so by this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-ref.html this is a Built-in Aggregate Functions use for sql query so it is better to explain and make example in answer cause the answers that are [barely more than a link to an external site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) may be deleted

Answer (score 2):

**Spark 3.5+** has [`count_if`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.count_if.html#pyspark.sql.functions.count_if) in Python API:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

test.groupBy('x').agg(
    F.count_if(F.col('y') > 12453).alias('y_cnt'),
    F.count_if(F.col('z') > 230).alias('z_cnt')
).show()
# +---+-----+-----+
# |  x|y_cnt|z_cnt|
# +---+-----+-----+
# | bn|    0|    0|
# | mb|    2|    2|
# +---+-----+-----+
```

**Spark 3.0+** has it too, but `expr` must be used:

```py
test.groupBy('x').agg(
    F.expr("count_if(y > 12453) y_cnt"),
    F.expr("count_if(z > 230) z_cnt")
).show()
# +---+-----+-----+
# |  x|y_cnt|z_cnt|
# +---+-----+-----+
# | bn|    0|    0|
# | mb|    2|    2|
# +---+-----+-----+
```