# How to check if the value at hand is in a particular column of some PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe, `trips`, on which I am performing aggregations. For each `PULocationID`, I am first computing the average of `total_amount`, then the number of trips, and finally, **the number of trips whose `DOLocationID` is in the `DOLocationID` column of `mtrips`, another PySpark dataframe**.

I'm including the schemas for both `trips` and `mtrips` below.

My current code is as follows but it is incomplete:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
cnt_cond = lambda cond: F.sum(F.when(cond, 1).otherwise(0))
(
    trips
        .groupBy('PULocationID', 'DOLocationID')
        .agg(
            F.mean('total_amount').alias('avg_total_amt'),
            F.count('*').alias('trip_count'),
            cnt_cond(mtrips.DOLocationID.contains(trips.DOLocationID)).alias('trips_to_pop')
        )
        .show(200)
)
```

```py
trips.printSchema()

# root
#  |-- VendorID: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- tpep_pickup_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
#  |-- tpep_dropoff_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
#  |-- passenger_count: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- trip_distance: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- RatecodeID: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- store_and_fwd_flag: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- PULocationID: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- DOLocationID: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- payment_type: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- fare_amount: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- extra: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- mta_tax: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- tip_amount: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- tolls_amount: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- improvement_surcharge: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- total_amount: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- congestion_surcharge: double (nullable = true)
```

```py
mtrips.printSchema()

# root
#  |-- DOLocationID: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- pcount: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: have you tried left outer join and then perform aggregations ? Would be great if you can provide sample data of both data sets to work with

Answer (score 0):

Here is the line of code that solved the problem:

```py
cnt_cond(col('DOLocationID').isin([i['DOLocationID'] for i in mtrips.collect()])).alias('trips_to_pop')
```